# How to retrieve a text file using Fetch API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

The URL below responds with a `.txt` file in web browser. How would I `console.log()` the data inside `.txt` file using Fetch API in JavaScript?

Here abovementioned URL:

`http://google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=python`

The promise is fulfilled but i didn't find a way to get the data inside `.txt` file

```
fetch("http://google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=python", {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582',
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      },
    })
```

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)?

Comment: From the duplicate, on the subject of `no-cors` mode: **Note that this won't let you do anything that you require CORS to do. You will not be able to read the response.**

Comment: Why are you overriding the `User-Agent` header?

Comment: Why are you setting a `Content-Type` of `text/plain` when you are making a GET request so you aren't sending any content at all (plain text or otherwise)?

Comment: That URL returns JSON, not plain text.